# How to run Make target when a file is deleted or an older file is added?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `make` target that looks like this:

```
WXICONS_TIMESTAMP = assets/fonts/.timestamp

# compile icons
$(WXICONS_TIMESTAMP): scripts/svg2font.js artifacts/icons/*.svg
    $(NODE_BIN) $< 
    touch $(WXICONS_TIMESTAMP)
```

i.e., it runs a script that compiles a bunch of `.svg` files in a directory into a couple font files.

If you *modify* any file in this directory, then the make target is triggered because the .svg file will be newer than my dumby `.timestamp` file. However, if you *delete* an `.svg` file nothing happens, or if you add an .svg file into the directory that has an mtime older than the .timestamp file, then nothing happens.

So how can I trigger the target when files are added, removed or modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of one of the only times it's reasonable to have a target depend on a directory rather than a file.  The modification time of a directory is updated when either a new file is created, an existing file is deleted, or a file is renamed in that directory.

So, if you list the directory containing the `.svg` files as a prerequisite of the timestamp target then whenever a file is added, removed, or updated that rule will be run again.

```
$(WXICONS_TIMESTAMP): scripts/svg2font.js artifacts/icons/. artifacts/icons/*.svg
    $(NODE_BIN) $< 
    touch $(WXICONS_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know you could do that.